# Memcache Failover

Tags: php, caching, memcached, scalability

I am using Memcache (Not memcacheD) . If I have 10 memcache servers and 1 of it fails does that get removed from pool automatically ? I mean when my application tries to make a request for cache will it ever try to get key data from that 1 failed server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it gets removed, but there is auto-failover provided if you have multiple nodes added. You can configure that failover behaviour here: http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php

Here is a quote from the documentation:

> Failover may occur at any stage in any of the methods, as long as
>   other servers are available the request the user won't notice. Any
>   kind of socket or Memcached server level errors (except out-of-memory)
>   may trigger the failover. Normal client errors such as adding an
>   existing key will not trigger a failover.

Of course, this assumes that all data is mirrored on those nodes, because you have to implement sharding/clustering on your application side.